# Pulling time ONLY from date/time value LotusScript Lotus Notes

Tags: lotusscript

I am trying to pull the time ONLY in 12 hour format from a LotusScript value.

For example, if the value is [3:00:00 PM] I want to return "3:00" and that's it.

Problems have been that I am getting "15" as hour.  I get "0" as minute.  Some of the things I tried return errors.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what will you do when you encounter a user (like me) who got their computer set to 24 hour time in their preferences?
If you really need to get "3" returned for 1500 hours (3pm), check if hour is greater than 12, then return hour minus 12...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend to use [format function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_FORMAT_FUNCTION.html)

here is an example:

```
Dim s As New notessession
Dim dt As New NotesDateTime(now)
Print strleft(Format(dt.Timeonly, "h:nn AM/PM"), " ")
```

Comment: Thanks...I ended up going with "Format(CDat(entry.ColumnValues(2)), "Short Time")"